# Error when trying update item options

Tags: list, error, list-item

i experienced problem, when trying update list item options, here need long wait and after receiving error, with corelation ID, which is c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
Error appearing not always, sometimes update items is without any errors.
I cheked in logs for corelation id, but not understand what can process the error. maybe someone can take a look in log?

> 07/19/2012 15:09:32.14    w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa45    High        System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being
>   aborted.     at SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )     at
>   SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet,
>   Int32 timeout)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.S... c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.14*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa45    High        ...qlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior...   c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.14*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa45    High        ...)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock) c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.14*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x1CBC  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa45    High        ...)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock) 8d4d561b-1f6d-4e27-be0c-1e1660376c97
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.14    w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x1DFC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (POST:https://my_site/Offline%20SMScreditlt/Forms/Testings.aspx)).
>   Execution Time=41231,571  d3fd6ecf-e847-434f-9f0d-7f89e4f91fb3
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.14    w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa46    High           at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean
>   bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId,
>   Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames,
>   Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean
>   bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish,
>   String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pUniqu... c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.14*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa46    High        ...eFieldCallback)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean
>   bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId,
>   Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames,
>   Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean
>   bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish,
>   String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pUniqueFieldCallback)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean
>   bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean
>   bM... c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.14*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa46    High        ...igration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut,
>   Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object&
>   objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean
>   suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion) 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean
>   bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemUIVersion)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues)     at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary
>   values, IDictionary ...   c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.14*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa46    High        ...oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.FlatCommit()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.HandleOnSave(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>   ASP.VIEWPAGE_ASPX__108152...  c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.14*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa46    High        ...3282.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)     at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpCon... c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.14*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa46    High        ...text, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr
>   moduleData, Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.14*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x1CBC  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     fa46    High        ...text, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr
>   moduleData, Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      8d4d561b-1f6d-4e27-be0c-1e1660376c97 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     tzku    High        ConnectionString: 'Data
>   Source=SRV-12\Sharepoint;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated
>   Security=True;Enlist=False;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connect
>   Timeout=15'    ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout:
>   15    c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012 15:09:32.16
>     w3wp.exe (0x15E0)                           0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation
>     Database                        tzkv    High        SqlCommand: 'DECLARE
>   @@iRet int;BEGIN TRAN DECLARE @@S uniqueidentifier; DECLARE @@W
>   uniqueidentifier; DECLARE @@DocId uniqueidentifier; DECLARE
>   @@DoclibRowId int; DECLARE @@Level tinyint; DECLARE @@DocUIVersion
>   int;DECLARE @@IsCurrentVersion bit; DECLARE @DN nvarchar(256); DECLARE
>   @LN nvarchar(128); DECLARE @FU nvarchar(260); SET @DN=@wssp0;SET
>   @@iRet=0; ;SET @LN=@wssp1;SET @FU=@wssp2;SET @@S=@wssp3;SET
>   @@W=@wssp4;SET @@DocUIVersion = 512;IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done; ;SET
>   @@Level =@wssp5; EXEC @@iRet = proc_UpdateDocument @@S, @@W, @DN, @LN,
>   @wssp6, @wssp7, @wssp8, @wssp9, @wssp10, @wssp11, @wssp12, @wssp13,
>   @wssp14, @wssp15, @wssp16, @wssp17, @wssp18, @wssp19, @wssp20,
>   @wssp21, @wssp22, @wssp23, @wssp24, @wssp25, @wssp26, @wssp27,
>   @wssp28, @wssp29, @wssp30, @wssp31, @wssp32, @wssp33,
>   @wssp3... c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     tzkv    High        ...4, @wssp35, @wssp36, @wssp37, @wssp38, @wssp39,
>   @wssp40, @wssp41, @wssp42, @wssp43, @wssp44, @@DocId OUTPUT, @@Level
>   OUTPUT , @@DoclibRowId OUTPUT,@wssp45 OUTPUT,@wssp46 OUTPUT,@wssp47
>   OUTPUT,@wssp48 OUTPUT ; IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done;  EXEC
>   proc_DirtyDependents @@S,1,@FU; EXEC @@iRet=proc_UpdateListItem
>   @WebId=@wssp49,@SiteId=@wssp50,@ListID=@wssp51,@ItemId=@@DoclibRowId,@UIVersion=@wssp52,
>   @NewUIVersion = @@DocUIVersion
>   OUTPUT,@RowOrdinal=@wssp53,@ReturnRowset=@wssp54,@SystemUpdate=@wssp55,@ChangeLevel=@wssp56,@OnRestore=@wssp57,@Size=@wssp58,@tp_Version=@wssp59,@ItemName=@wssp60,@IsDocLib=1,@MajorVersionsLimit=@wssp61,@MajorMinorVersionsLimit=@wssp62,@UserId=@wssp63,@Level=@@Level,@TimeNow=@wssp64,@ntext8=@wssp65,@nvarchar14=@wssp66,@nvarchar16=@wssp67,@nvarchar17=@wssp68,@nvarchar18=@ws...    c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.16*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     tzkv    High
>     ...sp69,@ntext2=@wssp70,@ntext3=@wssp71,@nvarchar10=@wssp72,@nvarchar11=@wssp73,@ntext5=@wssp74,@ntext6=@wssp75,
>   @tp_ContentTypeId =
>   @wssp76,@nvarchar1=@wssp77,@nvarchar3=@wssp78,@tp_Created=@wssp79,@sql_variant1=@wssp80,@sql_variant2=@wssp81,
>   @error_sql_variant2 = 1,@tp_ModerationStatus=@wssp82,@tp_ItemOrder =
>   @wssp83 , @eventData=@wssp84, @acl=@wssp85, @IsFirstRow=@wssp86; IF
>   @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done;; EXEC @@iRet = proc_UpdateItemInNameValuePair
>   @ItemId = @@DoclibRowId, @Level = @@Level, @InsertIfUpdateFails = 1,
>   @SiteId = '4C53625C-9018-4A04-BB00-884C42153645', @WebId =
>   'C1A1EA19-2B8F-4D77-A45D-2063DC04CFAE', @ListId =
>   '83D00FDD-529D-40BE-8491-BA547E3C49EB', @SelectFromUserData = 1,
>   @FieldId1 = '8C06BECA-0777-48F7-91C7-6DA68BC07B69', @FieldValue1 =
>   @wssp87, @FieldId2 =
>   '1DF5E554-EC7E-46A6-90... c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.16*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     tzkv    High        ...1D-D85A3881CB18', @FieldValue2 = @wssp88, @FieldId3
>   = '28CF69C5-FA48-462A-B5CD-27B6F9D2BD5F', @FieldValue3 = @wssp89, @FieldId4 = 'D31655D1-1D5B-4511-95A1-7A09E9B75BF2', @FieldValue4 =
>   @wssp90; IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done;; EXEC @@iRet =
>   proc_UpdateItemInNameValuePairCollated @ItemId = @@DoclibRowId, @Level
>   = @@Level, @InsertIfUpdateFails = 1, @SiteId = '4C53625C-9018-4A04-BB00-884C42153645', @WebId =
>   'C1A1EA19-2B8F-4D77-A45D-2063DC04CFAE', @ListId =
>   '83D00FDD-529D-40BE-8491-BA547E3C49EB', @Collation = 27, @FieldId1 =
>   'FA564E0F-0C70-4AB9-B863-0177E6DDD247', @FieldValue1 = @wssp91,
>   @FieldId2 = 'E7CB6F60-F676-4B1D-89A3-975B6BC78CAD', @FieldValue2 =
>   @wssp92, @FieldId3 = 'F427DC51-CE00-4046-AC16-B0E7EA470BA5',
>   @FieldValue3 = @wssp93, @FieldId4 =
>   '326B3638-0D70-4C07-A47B-12C6F71862CE',
>   @FieldValue...    c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     tzkv    High        ...4 = @wssp94, @FieldId5 =
>   '2CA89A62-EC91-4E54-AFB5-B32629F4F20E', @FieldValue5 = @wssp95,
>   @FieldId6 = '73BC629D-26B8-4066-964C-B8A6DC2B587F', @FieldValue6 =
>   @wssp96, @FieldId7 = 'BD15E286-4D99-408F-9AF9-DD94B3CEDEA8',
>   @FieldValue7 = @wssp97, @FieldId8 =
>   '8416AD52-C316-4BDF-BC5B-117427E4CABE', @FieldValue8 = @wssp98,
>   @FieldId9 = '37D1C6FE-5012-4107-83AC-93D83A9362BC', @FieldValue9 =
>   @wssp99; IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done; EXEC proc_ClearLinks
>   @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level, @wssp100;EXEC proc_AL
>   @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level,@wssp101,@wssp102,@wssp103,@wssp104,@wssp105,@wssp106,@wssp107,@wssp108,@Fld=@wssp109;
>   EXEC proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level, @wssp110; EXEC
>   proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level, @wssp111;;IF @@iRet = 0 BEGIN 
>   EXEC @@iRet = proc_EnsureTranLockNotRequired @wssp112, @wssp113,
>   @wssp114; END; done:...   c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.16*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     tzkv    High        ... IF @@iRet = 0 BEGIN EXEC proc_UpdateDiskUsed @@S,
>   1; COMMIT; EXEC proc_GetLinkInfoSingleDoc @@S,@DN,@LN, @@Level; END
>   ELSE ROLLBACK;  SET @wssp115=@@Level; SET @wssp116=@@iRet;'
>   CommandType: Text CommandTimeout: 0     Parameter: '@wssp0' Type:
>   NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'SMScredit/lt/Offline
>   SMScreditlt'     Parameter: '@wssp1' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000
>   Direction: Input Value: 'scan120718.TXT'     Parameter: '@wssp2' Type:
>   NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'SMScredit/lt/Offline
>   SMScreditlt/scan120718.TXT'     Parameter: '@wssp3' Type:
>   UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value:
>   '4c53625c-9018-4a04-bb00-884c42153645'     Parameter: '@wssp4' Type:
>   UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value:
>   'c1a1ea19-2b8f-4d77-a45d-2063dc04cfae'     Parameter:
>   '@wssp... c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     tzkv    High        ...5' Type: TinyInt Size: 1 Direction: Input Value: '1'
>   Parameter: '@wssp6' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False' 
>   Parameter: '@wssp7' Type: VarBinary Size: 8000 Direction: Input
>   Parameter: '@wssp8' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'
>   Parameter: '@wssp9' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '965'
>   Parameter: '@wssp10' Type: VarBinary Size: 0 Direction: Input
>   Parameter: '@wssp11' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'
>   Parameter: '@wssp12' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'
>   Parameter: '@wssp13' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '2'
>   Parameter: '@wssp14' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '2'
>   Parameter: '@wssp15' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value:
>   '256' c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x1CBC  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     btq8    High        ...)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock) 8d4d561b-1f6d-4e27-be0c-1e1660376c97 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     btq8    High        System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being
>   aborted.     at SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )     at
>   SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet,
>   Int32 timeout)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.S... c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.16*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     btq8    High        ...qlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior...   c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     btq8    High        ...)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock) c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           General
>     8kh7    High        The URL 'Offline SMScreditlt/scan120718.TXT' is
>   invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a
>   valid file or folder that is not in the current
>   Web.  c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012 15:09:32.16
>     w3wp.exe (0x15E0)                           0x1CBC  SharePoint Foundation
>     General                         8kh7    High        The URL 'Offline
>   SMScreditlt/K111.40500760.jpg' is invalid.  It may refer to a
>   nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is
>   not in the current Web.   8d4d561b-1f6d-4e27-be0c-1e1660376c97
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.16    w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Web Parts
>     89a1    High        Error while executing web part:
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean
>   bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId,
>   Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames,
>   Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean
>   bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish,
>   String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pUniqueFieldCallback)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrU...  c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313
>   07/19/2012 15:09:32.16*   w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Web Parts
>     89a1    High        ...pdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName,
>   Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID,
>   String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String
>   bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object&
>   pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut,
>   Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String
>   bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pUniqueFieldCallback)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean
>   bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean
>   bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin,
>   Gui...    c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313 07/19/2012
>   15:09:32.16*  w3wp.exe (0x15E0)
>     0x0E5C  SharePoint Foundation           Web Parts
>     89a1    High        ...d newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object&
>   objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean
>   suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion) 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean
>   bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemUIVersion)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues)     at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary
>   values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback
>   callback) c1941c35-10fb-437c-be9f-ead1d9efb313

Comment: We need a little more info. What kind of list, what's the content type of the item, is there a lot of data in other fields, are there a lot of items in this list (>5m items), what version of SharePoint, what version of SQL.

Comment: It is SP 2010 Foundation. SQL lite. List have ~80k items. Type is Library, in which we receiving mail attachmenst (~0,5mb each). List have ~10 columns.

Answer (score 1):

The above issue is actually a bug.

This can be observed on a Stand-alone server installation.

Repro:
Run:

```
Set-SPFarm | Format-List *
```

A part of the info will return

Servers : {MyDomain.loc, MyOwnCorrentServerName}

Unlike in the case of a farm installation, there is an extra entry
MyDomain.loc

While enumerating servers in the farm (

```
SPFarmTopology.cs,
private void FetchSPFarmInfo(SPList spFarmTopologyList) ,

foreach (SPServer server in sharepointFarm.Servers)),

AddServerDetails(spFarmTopologyList, ref serverName, ref index, server);
```

throws exception

for the server name "MyDomain.loc"

---

**Resolution**

*** of Invalid number problem is to change all Number columns on SharePoint list to Single line text. then it will start to work. Ehh. Great product but this bugs are really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 
`SPList.GetItemByID()` ? If yes, try using `SPList.Items.GetItemByID()`.

Also, check following:

- check that the data and log files for your content database (and the other databases as a mater of fact) are not full - autogrowth should be enabled for them
- if autogrowth is enabled check that there is enough space on the disk they are on
- if you are using SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2 Express versions check that you haven't reached the database limits: 4GB for SQL Server 2008 Express and 10GB for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.